# Структура json ошибка

Tags: golang

Использую структуру такого типа:

```
type user struct{
    Neme string 'json:"name"'
}
```

При сохранение Visual Code ругается на json и выдает ошибку.

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Это вообще не го у вас. В го `{` всегда на той же строке, иначе ошибка, и метки структур должны быть в обратных кавычках.

Comment: Уже по разному пробовал , все равно ошибку выдает

Comment: а кавычки там обратные? или прямые одинарные?

Comment: Спасибо что помогли , все дело в кавычках было !) Еще раз спасибо и с наступающим !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если внимательно почитать [документацию](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), то станет понятно, что там нужны обратные кавычки (те, которые обычно кнопке с <kbd>ё</kbd>, слева от <kbd>1!</kbd>).

И вот в таком виде

```
type user struct{
    Neme string `json:"name"`
}
```

все будет компилироваться.